# Disable Mailchimp double opt-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

I'm using Ruby on Rails and I would like to disable the double opt-it but have NFI how to do it.

How do I send the variable to the API?

Thank you

Comment: What does NFI stand for? On second thoughts, I probably don't want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `subscribe` method you might use in a model for adding a user to a MailChimp mailing list:

```
  def subscribe
    mailchimp = Gibbon::API.new(Rails.application.secrets.mailchimp_api_key)
    result = mailchimp.lists.subscribe({
      :id => Rails.application.secrets.mailchimp_list_id,
      :email => {:email => self.email},
      :double_optin => false,
      :update_existing => true,
      :send_welcome => true
    })
    Rails.logger.info("Subscribed #{self.email} to MailChimp") if result
  end
```

It uses the [Gibbon](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) gem. One of the key/value pairs in the hash is `:double_optin => false`.

The example is from my book, [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html), which includes a chapter showing how to build an application that allows a user to subscribe to a mailing list.